# Compilation error: type 'Int' has no member 'random'

Tags: swift

```swift
import Foundation

class Generator {
    func generate(_ count: Int) -> [Int] {
        var result = [Int]()
        
        for _ in 1...count {
            result.append(1 + Int.random(in: 1..<10))
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Compile Swift Module 'Base' (1 sources)
/eval/Sources/Base/Exercise.swift:10:31: error: type 'Int' has no member 'random'
            result.append(1 + Int.random(in: 1..<10))
                              ^~~ ~~~~~~
```

Comment: What version of your Swift are you using? These random APIs were added in Swift 4 (shipped with Xcode 9).

Comment: I removed all of the unrelated information and code from the question. The only relevant portion is the error and the immediate code related to the error. Please update your question and provide more details about the platform you are trying to build this code for and the tools that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The testing system may be using an outdated version of Swift that doesn't include the `random` member in `Int`.

In such cases, you can revert to one of the older methods for generating random numbers in Swift, such as:

```
Int(arc4random() % 10) // This has same result as `Int.random(in: 0..<10)`
```